# Gibbs Sampler Running Wild

Tags: r, self-study, monte-carlo, gibbs

So, I'm setting up a Gibbs Sampler using a multivariate normal model with a Jeffreys prior (working through the Hoff book on my own). There's also missing data to be imputed. I've checked my posterior distributions with several places online and everything seems to be in order. However, after 7-10 iterations, the values become extremely large and R ends up throwing an error. I can't find a bug with my code, but I know there has to be one. Any insights?

```
n = nrow(data)
p = 2

Sigma <- cov(data[cc,])
full <- data
O <- 1*(!is.na(data))
for(j in 1:p){
    full[is.na(full[,j]),j] <- mean(full[,j],na.rm=T)
}
means = NULL
sigmas = NULL
missing = NULL
for(i in 1:10000){
    thetas <- mvrnorm(1,c(mean(full[,1]),mean(full[,2])),Sigma/n)
    means <- rbind(means,thetas)

    CSSCP <- (t(full) - c(thetas)) %*%t(t(full) - c(thetas))
    Sigma = solve(rwish(n-1,solve(CSSCP)))
    sigmas = rbind(sigmas,c(Sigma))

    for(k in 1:n){
        if(is.na(data[k,1])){
             full[k,1] = rnorm(1,thetas[1] + Sigma[2,1]/Sigma[2,2] * (full[k,2] - thetas[2]),Sigma[1,1] - Sigma[2,1]*(1/Sigma[2,2])*Sigma[2,1])
        }
        if(is.na(data[k,2])){
            full[k,2] = rnorm(1,thetas[2] + Sigma[1,2]/Sigma[1,1] * (full[k,1] - thetas[1]),Sigma[2,2] - Sigma[1,2]*(1/Sigma[1,1])*Sigma[1,2])
        }
    }
    missing = rbind(missing,full[O == 0])
}
```

For example, here's output of means:

```
> means  
           yA            yB
thetas  2.441615e+01  2.471443e+01
thetas  2.408984e+01  2.418701e+01
thetas  2.398771e+01  2.503151e+01
thetas  2.425869e+01  2.770232e+01
thetas  2.314881e+01  3.750007e+01
thetas  2.548020e+01 -2.310756e+04
thetas  9.629871e-01  6.021771e+08
thetas -4.583258e+04  2.602714e+17
```

Comment: It'll help to link your actual dataset (a small sample will be enough), and list which packages you used.

Comment: Unless you want your question to migrate to Stack Overflow, you should provide the maths behind the R code, i.e., which posterior do you want to simulate.

Answer (score 3):

If you analyse a bivariate normal model $$x_1,\ldots,x_n\sim\mathcal{N}_p(\mu,\Sigma)$$under a Jeffreys prior, $$\pi(\mu,\Sigma)\propto|\Sigma|^{-(p+2)/2}\,,$$the posterior is$$pi(\mu,\Sigma|x_1,\ldots,x_n)\propto|\Sigma|^{-(n+p+2)/2}\,\exp\left\{-\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-\mu)^\text{T}\Sigma^{-1}(x_i-\mu)\big/2\right\}$$which leads to the full conditionals\begin{align*}
\pi(\mu|\Sigma,x_1,\ldots,x_n)&\propto\exp\left\{-n(\mu-\bar x)^\text{T}\Sigma^{-1}(\mu-\bar x)\big/2\right\}\\
\pi(\Sigma|\mu,x_1,\ldots,x_n)&\propto|\Sigma|^{-(n+p+2)/2}\,\exp\left\{-\text{tr}(n\hat\Sigma\Sigma^{-1})\big/2\right\}
\end{align*}with$$n\hat\Sigma= \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-\mu)(x_i-\mu)^\text{T}$$which means\begin{align*}
\mu|\Sigma,x_1,\ldots,x_n&\sim\mathcal{N}_p(\bar x,\Sigma/n)\\
\Sigma|\mu,x_1,\ldots,x_n&\sim\mathcal{IW}(n+1,n\hat\Sigma)
\end{align*}using the [standard definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse-Wishart_distribution) of the Wishart density. So I would replace $n-1$ with $n+1$ in your code. However, the true difficulty may come from a too high missing rate in that there is no guarantee the posterior distribution remains well-defined with missing data: in the extreme case when the entire data is missing, the posterior is the prior and hence not proper.

Comment: Can you help me see this question https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/498646/how-to-built-gibbs-sampler-of-mixture-bayesian-regression-in-r? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to replacing the $n - 1$ with $n+1$, note that the `rnorm` command takes as its second argument the standard deviation; you've currently entered the variance. Fixed below, and should now work:

```
 for(k in 1:n){
        if(is.na(data[k,1])){
             full[k,1] = rnorm(1,thetas[1] + Sigma[2,1]/Sigma[2,2] * (full[k,2] - thetas[2]), sqrt(Sigma[1,1] - Sigma[2,1]*(1/Sigma[2,2])*Sigma[2,1]))
        }
        if(is.na(data[k,2])){
            full[k,2] = rnorm(1,thetas[2] + Sigma[1,2]/Sigma[1,1] * (full[k,1] - thetas[1]), sqrt(Sigma[2,2] - Sigma[1,2]*(1/Sigma[1,1])*Sigma[1,2]))
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you help me see this question https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/498646/how-to-built-gibbs-sampler-of-mixture-bayesian-regression-in-r? Thank you.