# How to built Gibbs sampler of Mixture Bayesian regression in R?

Tags: r, bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo, gibbs

I am working on a Gibbs sampler of three parameters and we know the full conditional distribution of three parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: This is just a comment but to quote a long code, I put it here.

> ```
> for (ite in 2:NSim){
> #Full conditional for pi
>
>  pi[ite]=rbeta(1, sum(delta[ite-1,])+0.5, sum(1-delta[ite-1,])+0.5)
>
>  #Full conditional for delta
>  for(j in 1:4){
>   p1=pi[ite]*exp(-beta[ite-1,j]^2/(20))
>   p0=((1-pi[ite])*10^3)*exp(-500*beta[ite-1,j]^2)
>   cat('\n',ite,j,(p1/(p0+p1)))
>   delta[ite,j]=rbinom(1, 1,prob=(p1/(p0+p1)))
>   }
> ```

The error says that maybe $p1$ and $p0$ are NAs. My experience when checking this type of error is that. Instead of for loop, just give $ite=2$ and $j=1$. Compute p1 and p0 as your formulas. Check carefully if they are NAs or not. If the codes are symmetric with regard to $iter$ and $j$, and if you can correct the error for this case, it will pass this.